# Windows service get deleted when update the system from Windows 10 to Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-11-upgrade

I wonder why windows delete my service when I update the system from win10 to win11. There are three services our team develops, and they work fine on win10. However, when I update to win11, two of them are deleted. When I manually install the services, they work just fine. Is there a way to find out hy windows delete my services?

Comment: The process to upgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 11 involves reinstalling Windows then transferring your user profile and the connected data. Did you select the option to keep your data?

Comment: @Ramhound I did not see the option to keep my data. I just click the update button. If this is the reason the service is missing, why two of them are deleted instead of all of them? Besides, I find that when some windows10 update to new version(also windows10), the services also will be lost.